# $3+4i$ in exponential form with euler

Tags: complex-numbers

given, $3+4i$

$\sqrt{{3^2}+{4^2}}=5$

$\theta=arctan(4/3)=0.927...$

but answer given to me was $5e^{i0.6435}$

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: arctan(3/4) is 0.6435, which is wrong.

Comment: @user317339 I think your answer is correct. Perhaps the actual numer was $\;4+3i\;$ and you miscopied? Or there is a mistake in the answer given to you.

Comment: You computed $\arctan \frac34$, not $\arctan\frac43$

Comment: @MPW No, he did compute correctly $\;\arctan\frac43\;$

Comment: @Joanpemo: Yes, not sure why I wrote that. The *given answer* uses $arctan \frac34$, not $\arctan \frac43$. My bad.